# Creating and Accessing 2-dimensional arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm confused about how to create and access 2-dimensional arrays in javascript. Below is an array declaration in which I'm storing names of people and then the src for their image. When I try to access myArray[0][0] element I get 'D' and when I try to access myArray[0,0], I get Donald Duck. How can I access the img src myArray[0][0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg" ?

JS code:

```
var myArray = new Array(1);

myArray[0] = "Donald Duck";
myArray[1] = "Winnie Pooh";
myArray[2] = "Komal Waseem";
myArray[3] = "Hockey";
myArray[4] = "Basketball";
myArray[5] = "Shooting";
myArray[6] = "Mickey Mouse";

myArray[0][0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
myArray[1][0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
myArray[2][0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
myArray[3][0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
myArray[4][0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
myArray[5][0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
myArray[6][0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
```

Comment: I don't think you want a 2-dimensional array. I think you want an array of objects, such that each object has a "name" and an "image" property.

Comment: What you are actually doing is `"Donald Duck"[0] = "assets/scrybe.jpg"` - which obviously can't work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, to create an array, it's better to use the square bracket notation ( `[]` ):

```
var myArray = [];
```

This is the way you emulate a multi-demensional array in JavaScript. It's one or more arrays inside an array.

```
var myArray = [
    [], [] // two arrays
];
```

If you're asking if there's a way to declare an array as multi-dimensional, then no, there isn't. You can access them like this:

```
myArray[0][0]; // the 1st element of the first array in myArray
myArray[1][1]; // the 2nd element of the second array in myArray
```

Here is the code you were probably looking for:

```
var myArray = [
    ["Donald Duck", "assets/scrybe.jpg"],
    ["Winnie Pooh", "assets/scrybe.jpg"],
    ["Komal Waseem", "assets/scrybe.jpg"]
    [/* and so on...*/]
];
```

But since you're giving all the names the same URL, then you can use a `for` loop instead to do this faster:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i][1]  = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
}
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 any chance you tell us how to access the array length or size or other options. I created a dimensional array as you suggested. However I can not access the length of the array. Any suggestion?
`var GenreArray#counter# = [
         [], []
     ];

   <cfoutput> 
   
   <cfset i = i + 1>
   
   GenreArray#counter#[#i#] = "#Title#";
   
   for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    <cfset counterForTime = counterForTime + 1>
    GenreArray#counter#[#i#][#counterForTime#] = "#SuitableTime#";
    }
    
   </cfoutput>
   </cfoutput>`

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps what you really want is an array of objects:

```
var myArrray = [
  { name: "Donald Duck", image: "assets/scrybe.jpg" },
  { name: "Winnie Pooh", image: "assets/scrybe.jpg" },
  // ...
];
```

JavaScript doesn't really have 2-dimensional arrays, as such. What you can do is create an array such that each element is also an array.

```
var twoDim = [ [], [], [], [], [] ];
```

In your case, however, I don't think that structure will help much.

Comment: Fair enough answer with an array of objects but no answer how to access them.

Comment: @JackTheKnife ?? you access the array elements the same way you access any array element, with the `[ ]` operator.

Comment: To access the a multi dim array with a for-loop
`myArrray.forEach((item) => {
            let n = item.name;
            let i = item.image; 
            ...
});`

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot be done like that. Must either do:

```
var myArray = new Array(1);

myArray[0] = new Array(1);

myArray[0][0] = "Donald Duck";
myArray[0][1] = "assets/scrybe.jpg";
```

Or use JS syntax

```
var myJSObj = {"Donald" :"assets/scrybe.jpg", "Donald2": "assets/scrybe2.jpg" };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and I used minBy from Lodash

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#minBy

```
var objects = [{ 'n': 1 }, { 'n': 2 }];

_.minBy(objects, function(o) { return o.n; });
// => { 'n': 1 }

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.minBy(objects, 'n');
// => { 'n': 1 }
```